# How to instantiate Object or call setter to pass values from different Threads using java8 Labmdas and thread pool?

Tags: java, java-8

I have such old-style code:

```
ObjectToInstantiate instance = new ObjectToInstantiate();
Thread getFirstValueThread = new Thread(() -> instance.setFirstValue(service.getFirstValue));
Thread getSecondValueThread = new Thread(() -> instance.setSecondValue(service.getSecondValue));

getFirstValueThread.start();
getSecondValueThread.start();

try {
  getFirstValueThread.join();
  getSecondValueThread.join();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
}
return instance;
```

FirstValue and SecondValue are diffent classes, also I can pass them into constructor, not only setters.

How may i do this using ExecutorService or something else to avoid new thread creation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at [CompletableFutures](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) which are designed with the idea of returning values after a given period of time. You can also easily manage the Exception cases as well.

```
CompletableFuture<FirstValue> f1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> service.getFirstValue());
CompletableFuture<SecondValue> f2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> service.getSecondValue());

CompletableFuture<ObjectToInstantiate> combineFuture = f1.thenCombine(f2, (firstValue, secondValue) -> new ObjectToInstantiate (firstValue, secondValue));
ObjectToInstantiate myObject = combineFuture .join();
```

What this is doing is creating 2 async threads that return values. `f1.thenCombine` takes the values of both when they are completed successfully and combines the values from both to create your new object.

You are now not using the side affects of methods, but actually returning and moving around values to create your new object.

Also depending on how you have your constructors on your object you might be able to do

```
f1.thenCombine(f2, ObjectToInstantiate::new);
```

you can also do this for the async methods too

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(service::getFirstValue)
```

Also if you have an executor service already you can change

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> service.getFirstValue);
```

to

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> service.getFirstValue, myExecutorService);
```

Comment: whem i'm doing
 CompletableFuture<Set> firstValue = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> service.getFirstValue());

its returning UnsupportedOperationException

Comment: @Igor what is throwing that? Is it the service or the Future?

Comment: @Ashjava.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
but this works OK with unit tests, that mocking my Spring bean.

Comment: @Igor what is causing the UnsupportedOperationException, that would be the root cause, the CompletionException is just a wrapper around the UnsupportedOperationException

Comment: @Igor Normally you get something like this `java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed` then `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed
 at com.stuff.MyClass.myMethod(MyClass.java:20)`

Comment: @Igor Also what Server are you using? Some servers dont support the Fork/Join framework, so it might be worth using an executorservice `ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);`

Comment: i'm using weblogic 12c, and YES, problem solved with ExecutorService.
Do you know any goide how to configure my app to create thread pool with JVM start and for entire app in one place?
PS looks like exception was NPE, because of message = null

Comment: @Igor you mentioned that you were using Spring Beans, maybe create a bean singleton that returns the ExecutorService. I have also used weblogic, and it was the reason why I couldnt use parallel streams, as it didnt support the forkjoin frame work mentioned here -https://blogs.oracle.com/WebLogicServer/entry/weblogic_server_12_1_3

Answer (score 2):

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
List<Callable<Void>> tasks = Arrays.asList(task1, task2);

es.invokeAll(task);  // Run them all
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding "threading":

You turn to an [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), but then you can't use Threads:

```
Thread getFirstValueThread = new Thread(() -> instance.setFirstValue(service.getFirstValue));
```

Could become:

```
Runnable r1 = instance::setFirstValue(service.getFirstValue);
```

( you use a method reference here; instead of a lambda )

and then

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(whatever);
es.submit(r1);
...
es.shutdown();
```

Where: **you** make the choice which kind of service you actually want to create. Could be a threadpool, or something else.

But beyond that; your code looks strange. Why would you want to **set** fields in an object (with values that are fetched **immediately** using threads)?! I would rather step back here; and not try to translate your code into "newer" concepts; but understand **why** it is doing such strange things; and get sorted out.

In other words: the real problem of that code is not *how* it is doing things; but *why* it is doing it!

Comment: `Runnable r1 = instance::setFirstValue(service.getFirstValue);` does not work. The lambda expression is fine…